# Three.js - shadow is passing through wall

Tags: three.js, shadow

Disclaimer: complete noob to 3D programming and three.js

I'm prototyping for an eventual scene which will contain multiple walls, devices, etc... As you can see in the screenshots, the cube representing one of our devices, casts a shadow on the wall next to the cube, but the shadow also passes through the wall. The walls are set to accept shadows but not to cast shadows on purpose as the walls are displayed shorter than reality but are assumed to go to the "ceiling" and therefore should not cast shadows. Any ideas what I am doing wrong for the shadow to pass through the wall. Again I apologize for the likely trivial nature of my question, but at this point I've been looking at this for a couple days with no solution in sight.  Thanks!

[screenshot showing issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVLFt.png)
[another screenshot showing a different view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCYRj.png)

Comment: Can you post the segment of your code that renders the cube and the wall? A jsfiddle of your app would be especially helpful

Comment: That's because your wall is not `shadowCaster`

Comment: Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gmarkc/ep6fa7xv/64/) as requested

Comment: @mlkn, are you saying the wall needs to have castShadow = true for this to work?

Comment: @gmarkc sure, it works in your fiddle. It says that wall should be rendered in shadow map. If wall isn't in shadow map it doesn't occlude light.

Comment: @mlkn, is there any other way to accomplish this than have the walls cast shadows? I don't really want the walls to cast shadows, based on the UX we're going for...meaning the area on the other side of the wall could be a hallway outside of a room, which in the real world would not have a shadow based on the wall defining the hallway from a light inside of the adjacent room

Comment: So, the correct way of handling the shadow on the outside of the wall, is by fixing the illumination on the outside, not trying to find a way to selective choose which objects should cast shadow on that side. Using `castShadow = true;` guarantees the expected behavior.

Comment: @gmarkc to accomplish what you need you can try to split floor mesh into two - inner part with `receiveShadow = true`, and outer part without it.

Comment: Well, I have encountered this issue before and the way I personally fixed it was by
light.shadow.camera.top, light.shadow.camera.bottom, light.shadow.camera.right left values or to make the wall the same 3d object as the floor with THREE.Object3D()